# How To Create a Typewriter effect with javascript using .querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Was hoping I could get some insight into why my code doesn't work for .querySelectorAll but it works for getElementById?

I recently figured out that .querySelectorAll passes an array so I tried putting this code snippet I made into a for loop and the effect no longer works? Any chance I could get some insight as to why this code isnt "typing out" the same way it originally was?

Thanks in advance!

```
    <!-- HTML -->

    <div class="style">
      <p id="demo" class="type" onclick="typeWriter()">
        Click Me
      </p>
    </div>

    //Js global variables 
      let typewriter = "Write out this sentence";
      let speed = 50; //speed in milliseconds
      let p = 0; //number of letters in string


    //Js with .getElementById
 function typeWriter() {
    if (p < typewriter.length) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += typewriter.charAt(p);
      p++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }
    //Js with .querySelectorAll

    function typeWriter() {
          let cycle, i; //establish the cycle and counter
          cycle = document.querySelectorAll(".type"); //cycle includes the .type class
          for (i = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) { //for loop that actually cycles
            while (p < typewriter.length) {
                  cycle[i].innerHTML += typewriter.charAt(p);
                  p = p + 1;
                  setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
                }
              } 
            };
```

Comment: Since youve now put your `setTimeout()` function in a `while` loop nested in a `for` loop, you will have every `setTimeout` set during the same second instead of adding any delay. You can fix this by finding a way to call that Timeout function outside of both loops

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! I guess that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Sean false. The problem is not in the setTimeout delay time. The display is already complete even before any `setTimeout` fires.

Comment: Because the innerHTML += is in a forwhile loop which fires all processes within under a second

Answer (score 1):

Because instead of `if`, you are using `while`.

Therefore, `typewriter.charAt(p)` will be displayed almost immediately and `p` being incremented almost immediately.

Just change the `while` to `if` just like how you did it when using `getElementById`.

```js
//Js global variables 
let typewriter = "Write out this sentence";
let speed = 50; //speed in milliseconds
let p = 0; //number of letters in string

function typeWriter() {
  let cycle, i; //establish the cycle and counter
  cycle = document.querySelectorAll(".type"); //cycle includes the .type class
  for (i = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) { //for loop that actually cycles
    if (p < typewriter.length) {
      cycle[i].innerHTML += typewriter.charAt(p);
      p = p + 1;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  } 
};
```

```html
<div class="style">
  <p id="demo" class="type" onclick="typeWriter()">
    Click Me
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I am literally an idiot. I tried that about an hour ago and it wasnt working.. Must have been some other part of my code throwing it off. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the while loop and it seems to work

```js
  //Js global variables 
      let typewriter = "Write out this sentence";
      let speed = 50; //speed in milliseconds
      let p = 0; //number of letters in string


    //Js with .getElementById
 function typeWriter() {
    if (p < typewriter.length) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += typewriter.charAt(p);
      p++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }
    //Js with .querySelectorAll

    function typeWriter() {
          let cycle, i; //establish the cycle and counter
          cycle = document.querySelectorAll(".type"); //cycle includes the .type class
          for (i = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) { //for loop that actually cycles

            
                  cycle[i].innerHTML += typewriter.charAt(p);
                  p =p + 1;
                 
           
         setTimeout(typeWriter, speed)

              } 
            };
```

```html
    <!-- HTML -->

    <div class="style">
      <p id="demo" class="type" onclick="typeWriter()">
        Click Me
      </p>
    </div>
```